# How redirect stdout (stderr) of child process to socket in winapi?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, client-server

I want to make client-server program where server is main process and the client is child process. In client I want to redirect stdout and stderr streams of child process to socket. In server I want to make from socket file descriptor and read from it. In internet there is lot of info about sockets, but I havn't found any example of parent-child IPC via sockets for windows.

If possible please post here a simple code which solves my problem (or part). Links to msdn also can help, but I think I've already looked up everyting there and not found what I want.

P.S. Please don't suggest pipes. I want to do this via sockets.

Comment: This is going to be very implementation specific. I'll assume windows is the only platform and OS requirement. What compiler, IDE, & libraries are you willing to use?

Comment: I am using visual studio. I would like to use standart library and winapi, as a socket I prefer socket2. But also it's possible to use cygwin libraries.

Comment: Which parts are you having problems with - binding + listening on a socket, connecting the socket or redirecting the IO?

Comment: @Rup There are several problems. I want my real child process to be any executible which can be passed to server as argument of main function. And redirecting output is also problems. Also there is another way I can write to programs server.exe and client.exe. server will spawn client client will connect to server and then will spawn other anyprocess.exe redirecting its output to socket. Connecting is not problem, redirecting and making file descirptor is problem.

Comment: Well hate to break the bad news to you but winsock does not have a way to redirect stdout to a socket you have to use a pipe and some other process to copy data from pipe to socket etc.

Comment: @AJG85 Are you sure. Can you give me link where I can verify this info? Because in msdn I found that "SOCKET can be treated as file handle" (but never find how).

Comment: Yes, you'll have to pump the output through in your own code. You really can't just use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) which does all this (but runs on pipes)?

Comment: Thanks @Rup for suggestion. But this soft requires to be instaled in remot machine. And this is not good enough for me.

Comment: If you're the author of the client.exe program, why are you sending the output over stdout/stderr to begin with? Why not send it somewhere else first (like a stringstream), and then redirect it from there? IMO, you should be trying to catch it before it gets to stdout.

Comment: I'm not author of client. I just said that I can write client which itself spawning new process and redirecting its output. Also I mustn't use any buffered streams. They are very slow.

Comment: @Mihran Windows uses `HANDLE` for many things sockets are one of those exceptions in usage as far as I know it's because they aren't an integrated part of the windows kernel. MSDN also states the reason that although winsock2 can be used as file handles it's not recommended due to performance hits with non-winsock functions like `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` as well as not getting the correct error codes back with failures.

Comment: For reference here's the MSDN blurb on socket handles: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @ Mihran. Ok i don't get it. You can write a client application, but it is spawning another application that you didn't write? And its this second application underneath the client whose stdout/err you want to catch?

Comment: @Mihran: with regards to buffered streams, evidence is to the contrary - if you want high throughput, you use buffered streams.  If you want low latency, on the other hand, your statement would be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Netcat](http://joncraton.org/blog/46) if you can use this or find the source for the windows version somewhere on sourceforge probably this can use pipes to intercept stdin/stdout and send to and read from sockets with those pipes.

I know you said no pipes but there is no other way to do this with only windows API.  You'll need the following at a minimum probably:

[CreatePipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. But I have already done this via pipes)) But there othere problem. pipes doesn't support select() thats why I need sockets.

Comment: You can use the overlapped I/O model and `WaitForMultipleObjects` to read or manage from multiple pipes.  It's not as nice as `Select()` on a socket list but it's a way of _faking_ it.  How many clients do you have running that you would need to redirect to server?

Comment: Yes @AJG85 I can do also this way. But here is another problem. If I do this way then I need to read form pipes in non-blocking mode. In windows I can't make file HANDLES nonblocking I can only read in nonblocing mode via low-level ReadFile function. But I want to make FILE* from this handle then read via fgets.

Comment: `ReadFileEx` is designed for asynchronous calls. Pass in your handle to the pipe and use the `OVERLAPPED` data structure. You need to protect access with `WaitForMultipleObjects` so you can't completely avoid blocking to prevent **Bad Things™**

Comment: Thanks, but this doesnt help. I have lots of other code which works with FILE*, and I should make from pipe FILE* and for it I use fgets method wich calls ReadFile with no Overlaped structure.

Answer (score 0):

This is like trying to put out a fire after its started, when you should be trying to prevent the fire in the first place.

Since you are the proclaimed author of both server.exe and client.exe, rather than trying to catch stdout/stderr, and redirecting it to a socket at that point, you should re-engineer the client so that you're catching the text destined for stdout, BEFORE it goes to stdout.

At that point, you can send the output text to BOTH stdout, and a socket if you wished.

**EDIT: Ignore top half since you have later said you are NOT the author of client.**

Ok, second try:

Since you are spawning the "real" client, using a "fake" client, why don't you just intercept stdout of "real" client on stdin of "fake" client (open a pipe). Then have "fake" client send data back on socket..

Comment: I'm not author of real client. I'm just author of fake client which should only connect to server, then itself spawn real client which stdout and stdoerr have to be redirected.

Comment: @J T see comment of @AJG85s answer

Comment: The idea isn't to open a pipe between the client and server, only between "fake" client and "real" client. "Fake" client would still be sending its data over a socket, so your server could still multiplex all incoming requests and run on only one process.

Comment: Chris' answer below illustrates what I've been talking about.

Comment: @ Mihran: I don't understand, you have a huge reluctance to pursue the pipe route, yet looking back over your past questions, you have adamantly sought out how to implement IO redirection using asynchronous pipes in Windows. What gives? Why don't you share with us why you think pipes are such a bad idea to begin with? (Especially since code examples you've posted suggest this is already what you're doing).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
server talks with client
```

and

```
client spawns child
```

Here is an example from MSDN to create a [Child Process with Redirected IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Unfortunately, you MUST use pipes to get the IO from the child program to client.  No ifs, ands or buts about it.

Then you can use something like the following to get the information to server:

client comms loop:

```
while ( /* files are open */ ) { 
    DWORD dwRead;  
    CHAR chBuf[1024]; memset(chBuf, 0, 1024); /* always initialize your memory! */
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    /* read data from child pipe */
    ReadFromFile(g_hSChildStd_IN_Rd, chBuf, 1024, &dwRead, NULL );      

    /* send data via windows sockets to the remote server connection 
       represented by serverSocketHandle */
    send(serverSocketHandle, chBuf, dwRead, 0);
}
```

Your client, in effect, becomes a translator between a STDOUT/ERR pipe and a TCP Socket.

Comment: @Chris what do you want to say?

Comment: I have wrote in questions to not suggest pipes.

Comment: Mihran, you have to intercept STDOUT/ERR somehow if you aren't able to modify the executable "real" client. You really ought to reconsider using pipes.

Comment: @Mihran he doesn't mean IPC pipes, he means IO-redirection - which on a command line you do with `|` and call a pipe. He's still using TCP (the `send` in his loop)

Comment: You have to use pipes to get from the program you didn't write, and then you can use sockets to write to your server.

Comment: @ Chris - which is a helluva lot slower :P

Comment: @Rup @Chris Kaminski and @J T I can't use pipes due to problems I wrote under @AJG85s answer.

Comment: Explain why you can't use non-blocking read?  You give lots of things you can't do, but no reasons why.  We can't help you that way.

Answer (score 0):

The only environment I know that supports this is Cygwin. They are open source - try to peruse their code for ideas. It's guaranteed to be really nasty, though, with things like pumping threads all around.